# How can i append '\u' to a number and save the result in a char variable?

Tags: java, unicode, char

So I have a bunch of numbers that represent Unicode codes, so like for example:

```
int a = 6543
```

I want to add a '\u' at the beginning but then save the result in a char variable like this  (so after getting the result of this \u+6543 I want to save it in a char variable):

```
char b = '\u6543';
```

Comment: As a note, you want to *prepend*, but in any case have you tried just using `char b = (char) a`?

Answer (score 3):

The char `'\u6543'` has numeric value `0x6543` (i.e. 6543 in hexadecimal base).

Therefore, to assign the numeric value to a char, you should write:

```
char a = 0x6543;
```

If you must convert the `int` value `6543` to the corresponding `char` having value `0x6543`, you can convert to `String` and then parse the `String` as a hexadecimal number:

```
int a = 6543;
char b = (char)Integer.parseInt(Integer.toString(a),16);
```

You'll see that:

```
System.out.println (b=='\u6543');
```

prints `true`.

Of course, you can only do this conversion for Unicode values that don't contain the digits `a` to `f`, since you can't, for example, store the value `00a7` in an `int` variable (unless you add the `0x` prefix, but then you don't need any conversion).

Comment: How would i do this in a loop?

Comment: @TheHaruWhoCodes do what in a loop?

Answer (score -1):

In "C" we would say:  `sprintf('\\u%d', i);`

What you're asking for here is the literal string `\u` followed by the string representation of a certain integer variable as a number.

So, now go do the selfsame thing in "Java-speak."